# Editing a webpage with no source

Tags: editing

I am a new developer (as in just graduated on the 10th) and was hired by a company to do web development.  I was asked to do some minor changes to a site that this company acquired.  The problem is that we do not have access to the source code (apparently the people had a bad break up with their previous developers and cannot get the source, I'm not exactly sure).  Is there a way I can add links to a site and have it change live?  I have Visual Studios, the address, the links, and the videos they will go to, not a hard fix, but I don't know how to edit the site without the source code.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you can't access the source (which is on YOUR website hosting company's site) you have a problem.

Comment: We do not host it, we are simply doing some changes.

Comment: Maybe you don't host it but you should have access to the hosting company for your own domain.

Comment: Is it a 'live' website, such as a Ruby on Rails, Django, Sinatra, ASP, PHP, etc. site? Or is it a giant pile of 'dead' HTML files?

Comment: Turns out we eventually got access to their FTP so we had access to the files all along, they just forgot to mention that, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to talk to a senior or superior and get more information on how to proceed, because getting that code in a less than professional (or legal) way (e.g. using website rippers or something) would be a bad career move ;)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

interesting situation I should say, the company definetely didnt do its homework before the break-up
I am presuming you answer "yes" for the questions below

- Is your company the legal owner of this website?
- can you change the name servers or CNames etc
- The current website is not Flash or silverlight

if here - you have said "yes" for all the above.

- First of all navigate to every page of this website. File save as
  each of this page to html(make sure you choose webpage complete  -
  this will save all the images as well) I realise this will be static, but there is not much you can do here
- Get all resources  (stylesheets, xsds (if any) , any other images)
- Enrich this content based on requirements (i.e. add dynamic content, change logos etc)
- Modify the cname or nameserver to point to the location(webserver)
  you are in control.
- Deploy your enriched and tested code
- Educate your company to treat the developers well and when things go wrong, ensure transition is done well

I hope this help and good luck

Krishna